# Logistic Regression with continuous data using sklearn in python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scikit-learn, regression

How can I describe these points with a regression? In the example the
`LinearRegression` doesn't fit the logistic distribution of the points. The
`LogisticRegression()` from `sklearn` just accept binary data. My y-values are continuous from 0 to 1.
Do I have to transform the data or how do I get a appropriate model?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14])
b = [0,0,0.01,0.08,0.16,00.28,0.5,0.66,0.8,0.9,0.95,0.99,1,1]
data = pd.DataFrame({'x': a, 'y':b})

LM = LinearRegression()
LM.fit(data[["x"]],data[["y"]])

plt.scatter(a,b)
plt.plot([1,14], LM.predict([[1],[14]]), color = "red")
plt.show() 

LogM = LogisticRegression()
LogM.fit(data[["x"]],data[["y"]])  # doesn't work
```

scatter plot with linear model
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A logistic regression is generally used to classify labels, even though it outputs a real between 0 and 1. This is why sklearn wants binary data in `y`: so that it can train the model.

In your case, you have a sigmoid function `s(x)=1/(1+exp(alpha*x + beta))` and you want to find `alpha` and `beta`. I think the simplest way to do this is first of all to transform your data:

```py
new_a = a[2:-2]
new_b = np.array(b[2:-2]) # Getting rid of 0 and 1 values
new_b = np.log((1 / new_b) - 1)
```

Now `new_b` is an array whose values are under the form `alpha*new_a + beta`, so you can train a `LinearRegression` model on it to find `alpha`:

```py
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(new_a.reshape(-1, 1), new_b.reshape(-1, 1))
alpha = model.coef_[0, 0]
beta = l.predict([[0]])[0, 0]
```

Finally, you can see test whether this correesponds to what you expect:

```py
predicted = 1 / (1 + np.exp(alpha * a + beta))
plt.figure()
plt.plot(a, b)
plt.plot(a, predicted)
plt.show()
```

[image]